Plotting a QQplot from a logistic GAM fitted with mgcv and using weights
Here is a little script describing my problem.
I am fitting a logistic model in R using the mgcv package.
The dataset represent the occurrence of an event under certain conditions.
For this model, I need to weight each line of information.
library(mgcv)

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n, 0, 1)
y <- rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = plogis(2 * x - 1))
y <- cbind(y, ifelse(y == 1, 0, 1)) # convert the response to a two column matrix
weights <- runif(n, 0, 1)

# Fit the binomial GAM with weights
mod <- gam(y ~ s(x), family = binomial, weights = weights/mean(weights))

# Use qq.gam (from mgcv)
qq.gam(mod)


But I get multiple warnings
1: In fam$qf(U, object$fitted.values, object$prior.weights, object$sig2) :
non-integer binomial denominator : incorrect quantiles
2: ...
The fam$qf function is provided below. It uses the prior.weights from the model as the size parameter in the qbinom function. But the weights used in the model are defined as weights/mean(weights), so are by default not integer values (note that the normalization of the weights is suggested by Wood et al. to avoid changing the overall magnitude of the log likelihood, see "gam" help).
function (p, mu, wt, scale) 
{
    if (all.equal(wt, ceiling(wt)) != TRUE) {
        wt <- ceiling(wt)
        warning("non-integer binomial denominator: quantiles incorrect")
    }
    qbinom(p, wt, mu)/(wt + as.numeric(wt == 0))
}

Is there a way to obtain a correct QQplot from such kind of model?
Thanks

In part, I think this is because (from ?glm)

For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes...

which, if I follow Simon's code for the qf function is what's being assumed. It seems that Simon anticipated non-integer weights and explicitly warns you that the quantile won't be correct in those cases.
So, do you really need to weight your data that way? If so, you can't use the fancy reference bands from qq.gam().
You also don't seem to be able to trigger the use of theoretical quantiles from a Gaussian, which likely isn't very good for binary data. With my gratia package, I use a slightly different logic and you can get a QQ plot with reference bands based on the theoretical quantiles of a standard normal:
library("gratia")

qq_plot(mod, method = "normal")


But as I said, the reference bands aren't that useful, but also a QQ plot of deviance residuals from a binary model isn't that great a diagnostic either.

Thank you for your reply. Yes, I need to weight my data. Is there another way of doing this using a logistic GAM?  Also, I have done some research on diagnostics for logistic GAM and haven't found a simple answer. QQplot may not be the best diagnostic, but I have been asked to provide it (so I gave it a try! :-)). Do you have another suggestion for a better diagnostic?
